# Gracefully shutdown JBoss application

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, jmx, wildfly-8

I am looking for an approach to gracefully handle shutdown of JBoss (Wildfly AS 8.2). This would mean that all current requests are served and the webapp stops receiving further requests. I found that this is possible via command line in `version 9` of the application server -

```
./jboss-cli.sh --controller=remoting://<host>:<port> 
--connect --command=:shutdown(timeout=t)
```

Using this JBoss gracefully handles all requests for `t` seconds and gracefully shuts down (this would require an upgrade from version 8 to 9).

One possible approach would be to handle this in the `Java` application by maintaining a count of active requests and waiting for this number to go to `0` till a timeout and then exitting, basically replicating the above mentioned functionality.

I need to shutdown the webapp/JBoss remotely, so we are looking for a `JMX` (Java Management Extension) based solution. Does `JBoss` expose any such operation to gracefully shut down possibly via `JMX` or any other technology?

PS- `Ctrl-C` or `kill` commands donot shutdown `JBoss` gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

JBoss EAP 6/7 and above allows graceful shutdown via CLI and even:

> The signals `SIGHUP`, `SIGINT` and `SIGTERM` all trigger a graceful shutdown of the JBoss 7/6 application server. Those are signals are respectively the commands kill -1 $PID, kill -2 $PID(or control+c), and kill $PID.

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/18601

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Jboss cli remotely as the URL you pass in the controller param shows. You could even use the "REST" API to execute it.
The shutdown should be available from JMX.

Comment: as i mentioned, graceful shutdown via cli is not a part of version 8

Comment: or If it is not available on the CLI then it is not available as the CLI is a  generic client. You have to upgrade to 9 or 10 to have this feature.